# Units in Representation Of Energy Density Spectrum

Tags: thermal-radiation, spectroscopy, sun, wavelength, si-units

[image]

In most of the texts, I referred to The Axis being labelled with Units as shown above.
But I also found few images with different Notation **(1/Units)** Being Followed as shown Below. 
The units of the Axis is inverse of the actual unit. Is this representation specifying anything important?? 
[image]
The Energy Spectrum Density of Sun is:

[image]

And another Figure as shown below:
[image]

Comment: What publications are these examples from (in particular, what country were they published in)? I suspect the `/` is just being used as a separator. Or they could be indicating that the numbers (like "1") on the axis are the measurement divided by the unit.

Comment: Also notice in the 3rd example, on the y axis when they want to indicate a unit in the denominator they use a -1 superscript rather than a division symbol.

Comment: The second Figure is from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien%27s_displacement_law

Comment: @ThePhoton Kindly check the new figure(4th figure) I added. There they have used superscript for X-axis. Is it that the whole thing just mean normalizing value in axis to numbers without any unit?

Comment: What is the source and what is being plotted?

Comment: @ThePhoton  4th image shows the energy density spectrum at the surface of the sun.

Comment: @ThePhoton Is it done to normalize value in axis to numbers without any unit?

Comment: What is the source?

Comment: @ThePhoton Source is Unknown

Comment: Then it's hard to know what is meant. I've never seen this convention, but it may be common in some country I don't live in. It would be very odd to use one convention on the x axis and a different convention on the y axis though. Possibly this chart is just done sloppily.

Comment: @The Photon https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Solar_irradiance_spectrum_1992.gif
A similar Chart but With Different Terminology : The WAVENUMBER

Comment: that one specifies wavenumber rather than wavelength. Wavenumber is expected to have units of inverse length.

Comment: @ThePhoton So the Above charts in Queries Refer to Wavenumber on X-axis Implicitly?

Comment: Not the ones that say "wavelength" or "$\lambda$". The usual symbol for wavenumber is $k$.